# html5 local storage not retained on next launch of windows phone 8 app

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, cordova

We had developed a Phonegap based hybrid app for Windows 7 OS one year before and its available in store. Once Windows 8 phone is released, we tried the app in Windows Phone 8. The app is working fine in this new OS since its web based except for HTML5 local storage.

In that app, we stored user login details in browser local storage on first time app launch and next time onwards the web side business logic will access it and use for login in background. This is working perfectly fine in Windows 7 phones. However in Windows 8 phones (Nokia Lumia 620, 820), this local storage get deleted everytime when app is closed or force stopped (please note: within the session, the storage is retained. Its not available only on the next launch).

To identify the cause of issue, I created a simple html5 app in Windows phone 8 sdk and checked the local storage save/read options. I could save value and read it within the session, but when exit and open again those values are gone. However the same html5 page works fine in IE10 in the same windows 8 phone (i.e) values are stored and can be accessed when I visit the URL next time.

Giving below the sample HTML5 page code *[I tried both ways of storing values in localstorage: localStorage.key = value & localStorage.setItem(key,value). On the second time, I commented the save commands and replaced with read commands. That time I got the results as "null" & "undefined" respectively]*

Kindly let me know how to keep the browser local storage in windows 8 phone permanently. This is a client requirement and appreciate your quick support.

Thanks in advance.

**LOCAL STORAGE SUPPORT CHECKING - HTML 5 PAGE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="fname"></div>
  <div id="lname"></div>
  <script>
    var outputElem1 = document.getElementById("fname");
    var outputElem2 = document.getElementById("lname");
    if( typeof( window.localStorage) !== "undefined" )
    {
   localStorage.firstname = "John";
   outputElem1.innerHTML="First name: " + localStorage.firstname;

   localStorage.setItem( 'lastname', "Smith" );
   outputElem2.innerHTML="Last name: " + localStorage.getItem('lastname');
    }
    else
    {
   outputElem1.innerHTML="Sorry, your device does not support web storage...";
    }
  </script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work

```
alert(localStorage.firstname);
```

According to the [PhoneGap API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) you need to use

```
alert(localStorage.getItem("firstname"))
```

It also wouldn't have worked in your Windows Phone 7 application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The code block given before was to check local storage support in IE10. Hence used alerts. Replaced it with the device test code. I already tried getItem/setItem commands. They are working in both Windows Phone 7 & 8. However, in windows 7 phone, the local storage values are retained and available for next launch. **But in windows 8 phone, those values get cleared when we exit/close the app; during next launch, we need to enter values again - which rules out the purpose of local storage.** I need a solution to retain local storage values in windows phone 8

Comment: Yes, I understand what you need. But posting a code example that's obviously not valid hardly helps your case. However, I'm pretty sure your problem is your Windows Phone browser settings, and not your code. Try on a different phone/emulator, and try play with the privacy settings and see if they differ.

Answer (score 0):

Hi We also faced same issue, with this we used session here

as

```
sessionStorage.setItem(yourkey, yourvalue);
var item = sessionStorage.getItem(yourkey);
```

[here is the link](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/web-storage/)